# Facebook gets different og:image url

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

My website uses wordpress. I just want to share my essays from my website on facebook. My code looks like :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.dusunbil.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/İkonoklazm.jpg" />
```

However, facebook gets different url.

[Here is facebook debug page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dB2Zk.png)

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to review your image dimension

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices

https://www.wix.com/support/html5/article/recommended-facebook-share-image-size

Comment: size of image is 1200 x 600
I think it is enough, isn't it?
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200" /><meta property="og:image:height" content="600" />